# Web.config settings for ASP.NET Core web app as a sub-app within a ASP.NET Core web app?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Have "WebsiteA" trying to host another application "API" within it. Using a folder called "services". From what I've read in order for the sub-app to work I have to move my handlers up to the parent config. So being new to .NET Core I'm sure I'm missing something straightforward but set up the handlers in the parent something like this:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCoreAPI" path="services\*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />

    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\websiteA.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />

    <aspNetCoreAPI processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\services\api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />


  </system.webServer>
```

Seems that the aspNetCoreAPI tag is a no-no as the application rejects the configuration as malformed.

Ideally how should the web.config be setup in a the sub-application scenario for such an api application?

Comment: Yeah I was way off on my thinking, posting my resolution for other stuck in same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so the config approach is completely not right. Keeping the config vanilla in the parent app and making a simple handler exclusion (commented out) in the child application makes the magic happen for configuration issues.

Parent:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\websiteA.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Child:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <!--<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />-->

    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
```

They real key is that you need to make a really *gross* addition to the parent Configure method in the Startup.cs. (https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/416#issuecomment-149046552)

So I added this at the bottom of the existing logic in the method:

```
app.Map("/services", (app1) => this.Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory));
```

and in the new Configure1 method created I copied the Configure method from my child application:

```
public void Configure1(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I don't prefer the child app directory path and sub-application logic in my parent app as it is a tightly leashed coupling that just feels wrong. But that is where things stand right now as I understand.

Comment: I'll accept it as answer once tie passes and no better solution presents itself.